# Allowing website users to edit css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to allow the users of my php/mysql/html/js website to edit a css file, can that be dangerous in any way? I mean can someone hack my data using this and how?

thank you

Comment: You mean to allow users to edit a CSS file that will then be used in your site?

Comment: Do you want their CSS changes to be visible only on their client or by everyone ? You can make an html form, then use the values with js to change the stylesheet (this won't be saved though)...

Comment: Is it dangerous? yes. Can someone hack your site? Depends on your code. Can someone then use your site to ddos other sites/computers? Yes.

Comment: Yes i want to allow users to change the css that will be used in their own pages, but data from other accounts are also available  on the page...

Comment: Thank you jonathan, how about Ivan's idea of not allowing the changes to be directly injected into the file?

Comment: People could also run javascript from within css. Or inject pretty much anything onto your site client side.

Comment: OK, Jonathan, let's suppose i can parse the css code inserted by users to prevent any php/js from existing inside of it, will that remove the danger?

Comment: I doubt you could parse all of it out with all the ways you can obfuscate code. If this is something you actually want to do, I would suggest not allowing them to change css and just picking a few elements on your page and a few styles like background-color, color...etc and giving them the ability of changing those for simple customizations. Very controlled. I mean this all depends on what you are trying to allow. If you are allowing someone to modify their profile on a forum, be cautious. If you are hosting paid ecommerce sites, be more relaxed and don't worry about css as much.